# How to use custom isOpen with a chakra component

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I am relatively new to react and not sure why isOpen is not working as expected.
Please see the code below for the example that I am working with

I have a menu icon that is using isOpen to open navlinks:

```
const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
<IconButton variant={"unstyled"} bgColor={"white"} color={"black"} size={"s"} icon={isOpen ? <Hamburger size={"24"} /> : <Hamburger size={"24"} />} aria-label={"Open Menu"} display={{ md: "none" }} onClick={isOpen ? onClose : onOpen} />

{isOpen ? (
                    <Box color={"#b8860b"} pb={4} display={{ md: "none" }}>
                        <Stack as={"nav"} spacing={5}>
                            {Links.map(link => (
                                <Link key={link.name} href={link.route}>
                                    <Flex paddingBottom="40px" h="40px" borderBottom="1px" borderColor="black" justifyContent={'left'}>
                                        <Flex paddingLeft={"10px"} paddingTop={"3%"}> {link.icon}</Flex>
                                        <Text p={2} color={"black"}  >
                                            {link.name}
                                        </Text>
                                    </Flex>
                                </Link>
                            ))}
                        </Stack>
                    </Box>
                ) : null}
```

When I try using a custom isOpen to open a drawer component, i just cant get it to work..
What am I doing wrong?:

````
const { isOpenMenu, onOpenMenu, onCloseMenu } = useDisclosure()
 <Button
                        bgColor={"white"}
                      
                        onClick={isOpenMenu}
                    >
                        <BsCart4 size={"26px"} color={"black"} />
                        {cartItemCount > 0 && <Badge ml='1' fontSize='0.9em' colorScheme='green'>{cartItemCount}</Badge>}
                    </Button>

<Drawer
                    isOpen={isOpenMenu}
                    placement='right'
                    onClose={onCloseMenu}
                    finalFocusRef={btnRef}
                >
                    <DrawerOverlay />
                    <DrawerContent>
                        <DrawerCloseButton />
                        <DrawerHeader>Create your account</DrawerHeader>

                        <DrawerBody>
                            <Input placeholder='Type here...' />
                        </DrawerBody>

                        <DrawerFooter>
                            <Button variant='outline' mr={3} onClick={onCloseMenu}>
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                            <Button colorScheme='blue'>Save</Button>
                        </DrawerFooter>
                    </DrawerContent>
                </Drawer>
    ```
When I use isOpen for the drawer it works fine so I thought having another isOpen but custom would open the drawer but its not working as expected.  

Can someone help understand why my thinking isnt right based on how to use isOpen correctly? 

It seems like only isOpen works when I switch it from using the menu bar and drawer
````

Comment: I had a similar experience with both drawers and modals, figured it was a library issue. I updated all my dependancies and the change from @chakra-ui/react appears to have worked for me (2.2.3 -> 2.2.6)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to use custom names to the useDisclosure states, you have to set them like this:

```
const { isOpen: isOpenMenu, onOpen: onOpenMenu, onClose: onCloseMenu } = useDisclosure()
```

Also, the onClose prop of the drawer component is just a event handler, dont put your onCloseMenu function ther, just call it when you want to close the drawer, as you made on the cancel button, example:

```
<Button onClick={onCloseMenu} ... />
```